# How to continue text from the new line in html?

Tags: html, tinymce

I am trying to get custom template for the metadata HTML and using TinyMCE(built in option.
I have following code:

```
<p><strong>Report name:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong>${properties.name}</p>
```

The report name is long enough and it continues from the beginning of the line, like this:

```
Report name: kjadisjdiadiajdiaj
dsadasdadsadadadasdadasdasdasda
dadasdsadada
```

But I want:

```
Report name: kjadisjdiadiajdiaj
             dsadasdadsadadadasdadasdasdasda
             dadasdsadada
```

and my tinymce looks like

```
Report name:           ${properties.name}
```

How can I do that?
I am very new to the HTML (I do not play at all with frontend stack, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements in a `div` and make the `div` to have a `display:flex`. You can then style it further from there.

HTML

```
 <div class='container'>
   <p><strong>Report name: </p>
   <p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;${properties.name}</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
   display: flex;
 }
```